# How can I get assign value of success callback function result to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return "currentLoc". Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.
How is it possible to assign result of callback function to reuse it all through my code.

```
function currentLocation() {

    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {
        var crd = pos.coords;
        console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
        console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);

        currentLoc = new google.maps.LatLng( crd.latitude, crd.longitude);

    };

    function error(err) {
        ///ERROR

    };

    if ( navigator.geolocation) 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);

   return currentLoc;
```

}

Comment: `success` is Asynchronous, meaning the result returned from your `currentLocation` function may happen before `success` is run. Everything has to happen in `success`. Also, note that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` will prompt the user for permission to access their location every time it's called, whereas `navigator.geolocation.watchPostion` will only ask once.

Answer (score 1):

because the callback is happening asynchronously, your `return` statement happens before the `success` is ever even run.

an option would be to have your main `currentLocation` function take a callback, and call that with the value from inside `success`.

Comment: `function currentLocation(callback) { /*...*/ function success(pos) { var crd = pos.coords; callback(new google.maps.LatLng(crd.latitude, crd.longitude)); } /*...*/`

Comment: I used another method. IIFE and now I'm able to display the Map I want.     for( i = 0 ; i<  data.length; i++)  {
                      (function(x) {

                          geocoder.geocode( { 'address': data[x]}, function(results, status) {
              
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {